# Deferred Shading DirectX demos?

Tags: c++, graphics, directx, shader, hlsl

I've been reading a lot about deferred shading and want to try and get into it. Problem is I can't find a sample which demonstrates how deferred shading can support so many lights simultaneously - I found one demo which was very simple with a single light in Code Sampler and an nVidia HDR sample butnothing beyond that.

Would anyone know where I should go for a good introductory tutorial (with code) on how to have deffered shading with lighting? I can make it work with one light but one light is a bit too simple (rather obviously :P). Also I only know how to make *directional lights* in deferred shading code and it's nice an dall but somewhat different to regular ways of rendering lights so I was wondering if there wree tutorials or anything I could find or just reading material that would help me figure out how writing shaders and special fx in deferred rendering works?

Thanks fo rany help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

NVIDIA stuff is usually good: http://developer.nvidia.com/object/6800_leagues_deferred_shading.html

Here's a reasonable XNA tutorial as well: http://www.ziggyware.com/readarticle.php?article_id=155

In terms of blogs: [Wolfgang Engel](http://diaryofagraphicsprogrammer.blogspot.com/2009/05/deferred-lighting-particle-system.html)'s is a good start, and [Christer Ericson](http://realtimecollisiondetection.net/blog/?p=93) recently posted a bunch of links (in the Graphics section of his "Catching Up Part 2" post).

Oh, and the [G-Buffer paper](http://www.vis.uni-stuttgart.de/~weiskopf/publications/simvis04.pdf) is required reading too. Less practical, but a good review of the process and rationale.